# Loop through multiple CSV files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I am working with three small datasets and for reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EoZCwW54fCrl0uB4m15yZzimaQXJ-QW_).

From column 2, I wanted to read the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protocols = {}

types = {"data_c": "data_c.csv", "data_r": "data_r.csv", "data_v": "data_v.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
```

`data_c` is a `numpy.array` that has only one **unique** `quotient` value `0.7`, as does `data_r` with a unique `quotient` value of `0.5`. However, `data_v` has two unique `quotient` values (either `0.5` or `0.8`).

I wanted to loop through the `quotient` values of these CSV files and categorize them using a simple `if-else` statement (for example, as `if quotient==0.7: print("data_c")`) but I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Update: I have found out that this error can be resolved by using `.all()` function as in the following.

```
if (quotient==0.7).all():
     print("data_c")
elif (quotient>=0.5).all() and (quotient <=0.8).all():
     print("data_v")
elif (quotient==0.5).all():
     print("data_r")
```

However, this prints `data_c, data_v, data_v`. How can we fix this issue?

Comment: How do you compare the first element? Have you considered to use pandas?

Comment: No, I did not use `pandas`.

Comment: Would you like to see an example or are you against it?

Comment: No, I am not against it as long as it calculates the `quotient` of all the files as I included in the question and that's one of the reasons why I stick to `numpy` instead.

Comment: Are you skipping the first value?

Comment: Which value? Do you mean the first column or?

Comment: You say " read the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row". I'm wondering what happen when you read the first row.

Comment: Oh, of course, you start from the second or else you compare it against itself which is technically the same.

Comment: it looks to me that `data_v.csv` has 3 quotients `0.8, 0.5, 0.5030303`

Comment: I have updated it and now it has only one quotient.

Comment: It's not clear to me what do you want to achieve. Do you know a priori the quotient and you want to print the file with that quotient?

Comment: Was my answer any helpful?

Comment: Not really but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking to use the **unique** values of your `quotient` array to categorize your data. If this is the case, then you can easily leverage [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to help:

```
import numpy as np
unique_quotient = np.unique(quotient)
# For data_c this is just a single value
```

If you place that `unique_quotient` array in your `protocol_dictionary` then it gives you something to compare ([using numpy.array_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) for instance):

```
unique_data_c_quotient = np.r_[ 0.7 ]
if np.array_equal( unique_quotient, unique_data_c_quotient ): 
    print('data_c')
...
```

Comment: What if the quotient value is NOT fixed, let's say if the data has quotients between 0.68 and 0.7 (`0.68<=quotient<=0.7`)?

Comment: I'd recommend you ask a new question for that! But there is a way of course

Comment: I would have been grateful if you could help me here but Ok, I will do that and thank you so much. Approving your answer as ACCEPTED!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to replicate the process till the moment you get the quotients. Here I work with one file only

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read csv
df = pd.read_csv("/home/baobob/Downloads/data_v.csv", header=None)

# shift down element in column 1
df[2] = df[1].shift()

# this is doing in a vectorial way the comparative with a element 
# with is previous (which is now on the same row but in column 2)
df["quotient"] = np.where(df[1]<df[2], df[1]/df[2], np.nan)

# if we want to check the different quotients for each file 
# we use .unique()
quotients = df["quotient"].unique()

# if we want to remove nan
quotients = [q for q in quotients if not np.isnan(q)]
```